# Class hierarchy, autowire services for each specific subclass

Tags: java, spring, inheritance

I have a listener class hierarchy consisting of a base class into which I autowire a base service `MyBaseService`.

I extend `MyBaseService` to more concrete sub service classes so in order to make specific implementations for sub listeners.

Using Spring,
how do I specify that a 
***specific sub listener class***
needs to use a specific ***sub service class***?

Here's a diagram:

[image]

Code examples:

**Services**

```
public interface BaseService<TContext extends ProcessContext, TTabel extends Tabel> { .. }

public interface SubService extends BaseService <B, BT> { .. }

---- (Implementations of these interfaces in service classes)
```

Listener classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractListener { 

@Autowired
private BaseService baseService;

public someFunction() {
   baseService.DoStuff(); //SubServiceImpl Also have a dostuff implementation
   }

}


public SubListenerA extends AbstractListener {
    //I need to specify that we will now use subService so subservices DoStuff() is used insted of base services doStuff()
}
```

I don't want to override someFunction.

Comment: Can't you use direct class reference for that?

Comment: I don't think so, maybe i need to specify, sorry. The main part of the code will be executed by the base listener using the base service. I need to inject Service A, when user sub listener A, sub listener A1, sublistener A2, for that  instance. @11thdimension

Comment: It's still not clear, aren't `listenerA` and `serviceA` also spring beans?

Comment: @11thdimension The listener class are not beans. So basically when the base service is called in the base listener, i need it to actually be Service A og Service B depending on whether its sub listener A or sub listener B.
Does that make sense?

Comment: I thought of using @Primary, but that doesn't work when i have multiple sub services which can be candidates..

Comment: I'm not sure if I still understand, if you can post the sample code that you have it would be clearer. If `listener` are not beans then how would you mark them primary?

Comment: @11thdimension Updated with code :)

Comment: ok, I got it. However since there would be only one instance of `AbstractListner` and `BaseService` at runtime, it would be decided wheter base service is `ServiceA` or `ServiceB` at the spring autowiring. Then other bean would be useless, is that what you need?

Comment: @11thdimension Yea, i would say so. That is what i need.

Comment: You can use `@Qualifier("serviceA")` on `baseService` field to tell Spring to use beanID `serviceA`

Comment: @11thdimension How would I ever use Service B then? What i had a another service class inherinting from BaserService, called Service A1, how can Qualifier help me here?

Comment: That's what I said, since autowiring is done once, other beans would be useless. I don't think you need Spring autowiring in this case. You can't have a single reference pointing to multiple beans. You need to use something like factory pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create beans of `Listener` classes also, as they're going to be used finally to call service classes. Since we can't have same reference pointing to different beans, we need different beans for it.

Please take a look at the sample below,

```
package com.test;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestChildInjectionApplication {
    @Autowired
    private SubListenerA listenerA;

    @Autowired
    private SubListenerB listenerB;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init () {
        listenerA.doSomething();
        listenerB.doSomething();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestChildInjectionApplication.class, args);
    }
}

class BaseListener {
    private BaseService service;

    public BaseListener(BaseService service) {
        super();
        this.service = service;
    }


    public void doSomething() {
        service.doStuff();
    }
}

@Component
class SubListenerA extends BaseListener {
    public SubListenerA(ServiceA service) {
        super(service);
    }
}

@Component
class SubListenerB extends BaseListener {
    public SubListenerB(ServiceB service) {
        super(service);
    }
}

class BaseService {
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("################################## in: " + this.getClass());
    }
}

@Component
class ServiceA extends BaseService {}

@Component
class ServiceB extends BaseService {}
```